# how can i find specific letter in character in R

Tags: r, letter

there is a vecter

```
tmp <- c("a", "a.b", "c", "c.g.g", "rr", "r.t")
```

i want find index or true/false including "."

the result will be 2,4,6 or F T F T F T

how can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grepl` and escape the `.`.

```
> tmp <- c("a", "a.b", "c", "c.g.g", "rr", "r.t")
> grepl("\\.", tmp)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grep`:

```
grep(".", tmp, fixed=TRUE)
```